# big data problems: scaling up from sub sample to full set taking forever using glmer multilevel regression

Tags: r

I am using glmer to run a multilevel regression. The data has 2.5 million observations. I worked out the kinks using a sub sample, which always ran fast, but after I scaled up it just never finishes (left it alone for over 12 hrs).

I did some slices of the first x rows, and you can see where all of a sudden the time to complete jumps dramatically.

```
#slice 1:100000: 11 secs 
#slice 1:110000: 14 secs 
#slice 1:120000: 17 secs 
#slice 1:130000: 33 secs 
#slice 1:140000: 18 minutes 
#slice 1:150000: 26.9 minutes
```

I tried running just the rows where the time to complete slowed dramatically to make sure there isn't anything unreasonably funky going on there, and that was fine:

```
#slice 130000:150000: 4.2 secs
```

This isn't data I can't upload, and I have no idea how to make a reproducible sample that is over a hundred thousand observations. But this is the code I used:

```
start = Sys.time()
mylogit.m1a <- glmer(matt.3mo.move ~ 
                    rasValue_mt*flood_risk_simple + tenure.yr + CurrentAge + percap.inc.k + employment + rentership + pop.change + pop.den.k + 
                    (1 | GEOID ),
                    data = temp, family = "binomial", control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", calc.derivs=FALSE))
print(Sys.time()-start)
```

Any advice on how to trouble shoot this would be appreciated, or best practices for big datasets that I could trial out. So far I've relied on [this guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmerperf.html), but it doesn't seem like that will get me to 2.5 million.

EDIT:
Per Ben Bolker's link, it looks like I can use a [generalized additive model](https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-10-20-big-mixed-models/) to help cut the time (I did not know about these!); I'm a bit confused on the code example. Why are they using s(Subject, bs = 're') + s(Days, Subject, bs = 're'), rather than just s(Subject, bs = 're')?

```
ga_model = gam(
  Reaction ~  Days + s(Subject, bs = 're') + s(Days, Subject, bs = 're'),
  data = sleepstudy,
  method = 'REML'
)
```

Comment: anything useful [here](https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-10-20-big-mixed-models/) ?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about these, and they seem like they could work! I'm still a bit confused on the coding. I edited the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

With 1000 groups, 10 parameters, I saw a roughly linear increase over the range of 100,000 to 180,000 observations (although my runs were much slower than yours - 450 up to 1200 seconds).  If this linear scaling held up to 2.6M observations the fit would take `(2.5e6/1.8e5*1200)/(60*60)` = 4.6 hours.

My only guess about your situation is that you're running into a memory limitation and "thrashing" (i.e. your program keeps having to hand back and then reclaim memory/execution thread from the OS)?

Reproducible code (of sorts) below.

[image: timing of mixed model fits with lme4 and glmmTMB]

Here I'm using `glmmTMB` with parallelization across 4 cores, so the "user" (CPU) time is greater than that of lme4's, but the elapsed time is considerably less.

---

```r
library(lme4)
sim_dat <- function(n = 1e5, ngrp = 1e3, np = 10, seed = NULL) {
   if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
   dd <- data.frame(g = factor(rep_len(seq(ngrp), n)))
   vars <- paste0("x", seq(np))
   for (v in vars) dd[[v]] <- rnorm(n)
   f0 <- reformulate(c(vars, "(1|g)"))
   dd$y <- simulate(f0, newdata = dd,
                        newparams = list(theta = 1, beta = rep(1, np +1)),
                        family = binomial)[[1]]
   return(dd)
}

fit_dat <- function(d) {
  np <- ncol(d) - 2
  vars <- paste0("x", seq(np))
  f <- reformulate(c(vars, "(1|g)"), response = "y")
  t <- system.time(
      m <- glmer(f, data = d, family = binomial,
                 control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", calc.derivs=FALSE))
  )
  return(t)
}

s <- seq(1, 1.8, by = 0.1)
times <- list()
for (i in seq_along(s)) {
  cat("** ", s[i], "\n")
  times[[i]] <- fit_dat(sim_dat(n = round(1e5*s[i])))
  print(times[[i]])
}

library(glmmTMB)
times_glmmTMB <- list()
for (i in seq_along(s)) {
  cat("** ", s[i], "\n")
  times_glmmTMB[[i]] <- fit_dat_g(sim_dat(n = round(1e5*s[i])))
  print(times_glmmTMB[[i]])
}
```